# How can I identify a website category with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a web extension. I want to identify a website category (social media, online retailer, streaming...).
I've been searching for a database or an existing program but can't find one.
Do any of you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `URL categorization API`. There are different solutions out there. Here are some suggestions:

- Klazify
- Webshrinker
- WhoisXML
- NetSTAR Incompass

And a sample snippet for `Klazify API`:

```
var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://www.klazify.com/api/categorize",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": "Bearer access_key",
              "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            "processData": false,
            "data": "{\"url\":\"https://www.google.com\"}\n"
          }
          
          $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          });
```